# MySQL appending to a JSON field

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to write a query that would append JSON values to a JSON field in my database. I have a table called cart with three fields inside: `id type int`, `status type varchar` and `items type json.` So basically i'm trying to write a query where it would find my cart by the id and it would add an item to the end of my `item field` so far what i have is this:

```
SELECT  cart set items= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@items, '$', {"item_id": "5"}) where id = 1
```

I know this is not enough since it's not working for me, so could anyone help me? I'm kinda stuck right now.

Comment: You are mixing Select and Update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your current code is not far off, except you need to use `UPDATE` rather than `SELECT`.  I was only able to get correct behavior by using `JSON_OBJECT` to represent the key value pair which you want to add to the top level array.  Consider the following update query:

```
UPDATE cart
SET items = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[{"item_id": "10"}]', '$', JSON_OBJECT('item_id', '5'))
WHERE id = 1;
```

### Demo